# ReactJS Component Interacting with Snap SVG Element

Tags: reactjs, snap.svg

I am new to ReactJS. I am trying to write a simple drawing app. The idea is to click on a canvas to create a rectangle or a circle and when that object is created i want to render a properties form (width\height etc..) that is binded to that element. So when the user would change the element or the values in the properties component the other would change (Two way data binding?). The elements have a dict called 'attr' which can be used as the state of the component, but i can't think of a way to update the state when the element changes on the canavas by manipulation or update the element when the component form values change. Can i pass the SVG object by reference to a component instance ?

Comment: Not so familiar with React, would it be possible to show a working on example on a jsfiddle or jsbin for example ?

Comment: You should be able to use [React refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to get the instance of the DOM element.

Comment: Were you able to do it?